# Odoo set Sequence in Product Code and Product Barcode

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have created new fields `Product Code` and `Product Barcode` for using when `Product Variant` is created.I have created this fields in both `product.template` and `product.product` and then when a product is created in `Product Template` with `Product Code` and `Product Barcode`, I want to create a Sequenced `Product Code` and `Product Barcode` for `Product Variants` which will come under `product.product`.
Eg:If we give `abc` as `Product Code` in `Product Template` and it have 3 variants, `Product Code` in `Product Template` should come as `abc-1`,abc-2`,abc-3` respectively.
Data passing and all is done but in my logic if we delete a variant and add another variant there is a chance it will come in same name.
Eg: If we delete variant `abc-1` and add another variant , its `Product Code` will come as `abc-3` (which is already available)

> Code

```
for variant_ids in to_create_variants:
    if self.product_variant_count == 0 :
        count = count + 1
    else :
        count = self.product_variant_count + 1
        new_variant = Product.create({
                        'product_tmpl_id': tmpl_id.id,
                        'attribute_value_ids': [(6, 0, variant_ids.ids)],
                        'xn_product_code' :  str(tmpl_id.xn_product_code_tmpl) +  "-" + str(count),
                        'xn_product_barcode' : str(tmpl_id.xn_product_barcode_tmpl) + "-" + str(count) 
                    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an extra count field to the `Product Template`